# how to construct this query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds info about videos on a website.  It has fields for id (primary key),title, series (int, foreign key constraint), and episode number.  There is another table called "series" that indexes video series.  So for example, series "American Dad" would have a series id of 1, and the id column in the series table is the same as the series column in the videos table.

I am trying to create a query that, when given a video id, pulls the title and video id of the previous and next videos in the series, e.g. if I input an id for episode 5 for American Dad, I would also get back the info for episodes 4 and 6.

I know how to write the query to find the series id when given a video id, and I know how to write the query to find all the episodes of a series when given a series id.  I am having trouble putting it all together in one query, and also limiting it to the results immediately preceding and following (based on episode number) of a given video.

Hopefully that wasn't too convoluted.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the episode numbers are always sequential, you can just do something like

```
SELECT ... WHERE (episode = :episode - 1 OR episode = :episode + 1) AND series = :series
```